# TAnimate does nothing when Active is set to true

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I am using BDS2006 on Win 7 x64 Pro.
These are my steps:

- Create a new application
- Put a TAnimate on the form
- Select "aviFindfile" as CommonAvi
- Activate the component at design time
- Run

Nothing happens. Anybody's seen this before?

Thanks!

Comment: The control is known to work. Perhaps the avi is duff.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, if you have a Win7 x64, it's very easy to check if it's currently working with common AVIs. My suspect is that, since Win7 doesn't use that AVI anymore, it might not work at all on this Operating System. But that's just me, I could be wrong.

Comment: I just tried looking for AVI files on my machine and the ones in "Common files\Microsoft\Ink\en-US" are all black. What the heck.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot make this thing work either ......

Comment: I have just tried this in Delphi 7. When I run the application on Windows 7 64 bit no animation is seen and TAnimate component is returning 0 as number of frames so I uspect that the aniation doesent even get loaded. But if I run this same application inside virtual machine with WindowsXP the animation runs just fine and TAnimate component is returning 8 as the nimber of frames in animation. So I gues there were some changes in the way how each windows stores the common animations.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a TShellResources component to make it work.

Comment: I can't see such a component in BDS 2006. Do you know what component do I need to add in that version?

Comment: I cannot check for BDS 2006. The unit containing this component merely includes some res files. If those are not available in BDS 2006, sorry.

Comment: If somebody can confirm that adding the component makes it work, I'll accept your answer, bow my head in sadness and go away...

Comment: Yes, this works. So it seems EMBT comes with their own set of animations...

Comment: Adding the component is the point and click way to do it. Simpler is just to add the `ShellAnimations` unit to the .dpr uses clause.

Comment: Add {$R copyfile.res} to your project.  If you do not have the resource files in BDS 2006, it is not unlikely that they can be sourced elsewhere.